# C# REST API: Allowing call from trusted Server

Tags: c#, rest, security

I have two Web Servers running the same C# Web Service.

I want Server 1 to call Server 2's WEB API to get data.

However, I only want Server 1 to be able to call it, I don't want clients to be able to call it:

```
[HttpGet]
      public HttpResponseMessage GetData()
      {
                If(IsCallFromInternalWebServer() ) // Call is from other server
                 {
                        // return Data
                 }
                 Else 
                 {
                     return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
                 }

      }
```

I can get the IP address of the call as follows:

```
public static string GetCallerIP(HttpRequest request)
{
    string ip = request.Headers["X-Forwarded-For"]; // AWS compatibility

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ip))
    {
        ip = request.UserHostAddress;
    }
    return ip;
}
```

Would this be a good way of allowing the call, by checking the IP Address.

Is there a better way?

Comment: A few things. If Server 2 is supposed to be consumed internally, why expose it to public in the first place? Another way to authenticate callers is through tokens. You can consider using OAuth/JWT tokens to identify the caller; as most request headers can be fairly easily tampered with.

Comment: I agree with PoweredByOrange. Don't open up the machine with the 2nd service outside of your network and you need not do any fancy finagling.

Comment: How else would I expose the call though to the other server?

Comment: @Robben_Ford_Fan_boy is the other server on a different domain? IIS supports white-listing specific IP addresses. That's another option. Otherwise consider using authentication tokens.

Comment: Yep. Authentication tokens are great. But you still need a method of granting the token. Tokens are not a solution themselves

Answer (score 1, accepted):

External and internal calls should not be mixed on the same service. I mean, if on a service you have calls (actions) that need to be called by clients on the internet, and also ones that are internal and should be accessible only to your own services, then this service should be separated into two, a public and an internal one. This would greatly reduce the attack surface.

When that's already the case, an internal service should not have a public endpoint, ie. in Azure or AWS you should not assign a public IP address to that service. You can still access it from your other services via its internal IP. However, as an example of defense in depth, you should still implement proper authentication on the backend one too. Restricting the IP address of callers can be helpful and may mitigate the risk somewhat, but it should not be the only layer of security.

As for authentication on the backend (internal) service, as you are talking about C#.NET Web API, windows authentication is the easy option, you can set it up in IIS and you can authorize the identity running your other application (or service) to call the internal one. Note though that this is an inherent trust, if there is no further authorization in the internal service, a compromise of the frontend one will automatically be a full compromise of the backend one too.

You can also use tokens (OAuth, JWT or else) as recommended by others in comments, but you are right, those tokens will then need to be managed somehow, however, as this is not about authenticating external clients but your internal applications or services only, this may not be so hard actually.

Comment: Just to clarify, both servers already have public API. So restrictions in IIS won't be an option.

Comment: But that's kind of the point of what I was trying to say. If "external" and "internal" calls are separate, then it should be two separate services. Sorry if I misunderstood the question, I'm happy to remove my answer.

Comment: I don't know how a REST API can be internal though

Comment: Why could it not be? Maybe I'm not getting something. :) You may very well have internal functionality in backend services that only your frontend stuff calls and you don't want to expose it to the internet.

Comment: That's exactly what I want!  But a Service is either callable via http/https or its not right?

Comment: Yep, but if internal functionality is in a separate service, you could put that service behind a firewall without a direct external IP address, or in a cloud environment you could not assign it a public IP address and use it via its local IP not accessible from outside. This internal service could authenticate its callers (your external applications or services) via Windows auth or tokens or client certificates or whatever, it would just be an internal thing for yourself.

Comment: That's the thing though, both servers are web servers with a load of client exposed APIs. Its just one API need to "hide"

Comment: I'm not a web expert btw!  I'm just explaining my thought process

Comment: Yeah, if it's just one single call, I understand why you don't want to create a whole new service. However, maybe you could refactor the whole thing into multiple layers as in multi-tier architecture. I suspect there is lots of functionality now on your frontend layer that could be hidden behind a firewall. While that obviously has a cost, the benefit is more overall security. If this is too expensive compared to the value you are protecting, you may be right to try to come up with something for that single call, but it's not the best practice and it sounds like adding technical debt.

Comment: I agree with that principal, however my understanding of a firewall rule is that it will apply to the whole server. So you can't restrict some calls, and not others.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129669/discussion-between-gabor-lengyel-and-robben-ford-fan-boy).